# Explain solution of this system of non-linear congruence equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

So I have a system of non-linear congruence equations (i may be wrong in terms):
\begin{cases} x^3 \equiv 21\ (\textrm{mod}\ 23) \\ x^5 \equiv 17\ (\textrm{mod}\ 23) \end{cases}
Somewhere I've read that to solve this system one should:

1. Find the solution of $3\cdot a + 5\cdot b = 1$ with Extended Euclidean Algorithm
2. Use $a$ and $b$ values from previous step in the next formula: $x \equiv 21^a\times17^b\ (\textrm{mod}\ 23)$
3. If $a$ or $b$ is negative, then calculate the modular inverse of $21$ or $17$ and use it in second formula with $-a$ or $-b$

And I don't understand why is it working. I've tried to perform some calculations to get the second formula but didn't succeeded. : (


Can you please explain me this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. Jack D'Aurizio's solution is correct, but in my case i just wanted to understand why is solution from the question working.

---

So we have a system of non-linear congruence equations.

1. We can see that $gcd(3, 5) = 1$ (greatest common divisor of exponents), and because of that $\exists a,b : 3a+5b=1$. After solving this with Extended Euclidean Algorithm we have $a=2$ and $b=-1$.
2. Now let's multiply first congruence by $a$ — $(x^3)^2 \equiv 21^2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 23)$
3. And the second one by $b$ — $(x^5)^{-1} \equiv 17^{-1}\ (\textrm{mod}\ 23)$
4. After that we have to "open exponent brackets", multiply the equations and finally find $x$:
   \begin{equation}x^6\times x^{-5}\ \equiv\ 21^2\times 17^{-1}\ (\textrm{mod}\ 23)\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}x\ \equiv\ 4\times 19\ (\textrm{mod}\ 23)\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}x\ \equiv\ 7\ (\textrm{mod}\ 23)\end{equation}

---

So as you can see, we've used Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find special exponents that will lead to reducing $x$'s exponent after equations multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither $3$ or $5$ are divisors of $\varphi(23)=22$, both the maps
$$ f:x\mapsto x^3,\qquad g:x\mapsto x^5 $$
are bijective on $\mathbb{F}_{23}$. In particular, since $3^{-1}\equiv 15\pmod{22}$ and $5^{-1}\equiv 9\pmod{22}$,
$$ f^{-1}:x\mapsto x^{15},\qquad g^{-1}:x\mapsto x^9 $$
and $x^3\equiv 21\pmod{23}$ is equivalent to $x\equiv 7\pmod{23}$, as well as $x^5\equiv 17\pmod{23}$ is equivalent to $x\equiv 7\pmod{23}$. So $\color{red}{x\equiv 7\pmod{23}}$ is the wanted solution.

Comment: i'm sorry, i can't understand how did you get that $x^3\equiv 21\pmod{23}$ is equivalent to $x\equiv 7\pmod{23}$

Comment: @EugeneKorobov: $x^3\equiv 21\pmod{23}$ is equivalent to $x\equiv 21^{15}\pmod{23}$, and $21^{15}\equiv 7\pmod{23}$.

Comment: @JackDaurizio: got it, thanks a lot

Comment: @JackDaurizio: i'm sorry to bother you, but i have one more question. i understood the logic of your answer, but that is not exactly what i need -- i'm exploring different RSA flaws and i can't to calculate Euler function for 23 (just imagine that). so can you please explain me a solution with extended Euclidean algorithm from the question or how to solve this system without Euler function?

Comment: @EugeneKorobov: what is difficult in computing $\varphi(p)$ when $p$ is a prime? We just have $\varphi(p)=p-1$, since every integer in the range $[1,p]$, with the exception of $p$ only, is coprime with $p$.

Comment: You may just forget about the Euler $\varphi$ function and prove that the maps $x\mapsto x^3$ and $x\mapsto x^{15}$ are inverse maps in $\mathbb{F}_{23}^*$ by Fermat's little theorem: $$ x^{3\cdot 15}\equiv x^{2\cdot 22+1}\equiv 1\pmod{23}$$

Comment: @JackDaurizio: i'm sorry, i've provided bad example... in RSA modulo is not prime, but a multiplication of two big primes

Comment: @EugeneKorobov: all right, but what RSA has to do with the current question?

Comment: @JackDaurizio: i'm trying to understand this solution (http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/rsa-cracking-the-same-message-is-sent-to-two-different-people-problem)

Comment: @JackDaurizio: can you please help me?

Comment: @EugeneKorobov: I actually helped you with the proposed question. If your main concern is about something slightly different, it is best to ask a separate question, just for clarity and order.

Comment: @JackDaurizio: you showed me how can one solve this system, and i really appreciate your help, because i've learned some new things from your answer and seems like i understood it, but my question was about explaining another solution, slightly different as you said : (